# i would like to illustrate some poems and compile them into a book. Would it be okay to publish it?

Tags: self-publishing

I'm an artist and I want to illustrate some of my favorite poems in a book. The poems are mostly from before 1900.

Question #1: **Is it alright to illustrate them?**

Question #2: **Would it be alright if the compilation is published?**

Comment: Welcome to writing SE.  What is good form on this site is to only ask questions after doing some preliminary research on your own first, such as by googling your question. I mention this because you could easily have found the answer to your copyright question with a simple google search. Have a nice day, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it alright to illustrate them?

Sure. I don't see why it wouldn't be.

> Is it alright if the compilation is published?

This is harder to answer. The poems from before 1900 will all be in the public domain by now, so you should be able to re-publish them without any sort of copyright issues. You'll have to check each of the remaining poems and, if they're still under copyright, you'll have to either omit them from the book or go without publishing it.

Comment: Building on @F1Krazy's answer - if you find they are still under copyright, you can contact the copyright holder and ask permission to publish it. The next question is how to find out if a poem is still under copyright. You may need to figure out the publisher of whatever compilation the poem was in and contact them.

Answer (score 0):

For poems,

> Copyrights last for the life of the author and for 70 years after that. With works that are commissioned by an individual or organization, the copyright lasts for 95 years after the work was first published. If not published it can last for 120 years after its creation. Many poems are in the public domain. This means they can be used by anyone.

[Fuller explanation here.](https://legalbeagle.com/7524772-copyright-laws-using-poem.html)